# jQuery UI Sliders - multiples slider(not range) at same position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to create a slider with 2 handlers with no dependancies to each other so it is not a range slider.

I`ve altered the css of both so that one apear above the line and one under it. When I inspect the slider at run time I can see that they overlap a bit but 3/4 of each slider does not

my problem is if I set both handler to the same value, when I try to change a value, jquery give me the control of the last one I`ve moved even if I click on the other one in a part where it dosen't overlap. seem like the slider engine give me control of this slider because in a range slider situation this will make sense(as they usualy completely overlap).

I use simple slider loading :

```
$( "#slider1" ).slider(
    {
      min: 1,
      max: 11,
      step: 1,
      values: [5,5],
       slide: function(event, ui) {
          if(ui.value > 10){
              return false;
          }

      }
    }
  );
```

anyone got any idea how I could bypass this?

here is the fiddle of it : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LmZ6A/)

Comment: You need to paste here some code to understand the problem ... also you can make a Fiddle with your issue.

Comment: Well it suddenly struck me, I could simply make 2 sliders and handle dependency myself. but I am still interested to know if anyone got a better solution using a single slider with 2 handlers